# How remove the last comma in my string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've been trying to figgure out using substr, rtrim and it keeps removing all the commas. And if it doesn't nothing shows up. So I am basicly stuck and require some help.. Would've been apriciated.

```
        if(is_array($ids)) {
        foreach($ids as $id) {
            $values = explode(" ", $id);
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $value .= ', ';
                echo ltrim($value, ', ') . '<br>';

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, it's easier to help answer your question if you provide sample input, the desired output, and the output that you're currently getting so that it's obvious where the problem is.

Comment: edit with the value of $ids

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )

Comment: Unclear what you are asking- Please improve your question with a few more details/code

Comment: I would like to retrive data from multiple ids at once. so it has to be 1,2,3,4 and not 1,2,3,4,

Comment: See my answer, with 2 diferents solutions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to take an array of strings of space separated ids and flatten it into a comma separated list of the ids.

If that is correct you can do it as:

```
$arr = [
    'abc def ghi',
    'jklm nopq rstu',
    'vwxy',
];
$list = implode(', ', explode(' ', implode(' ', $arr)));
echo $list;
```

output:

```
abc, def, ghi, jklm, nopq, rstu, vwxy
```

Comment: You're welcome and to answer your second question: change 'where id = ({$ids)' to 'where id in ({$ids})' equal is only for equality. Use 'in' to test for presence in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Change ltrim by rtrim:

> ltrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string
>
> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

```
<?php

$ids = Array ( 1,2,3,4 ); 
$final = '';

        if(is_array($ids)) {
        foreach($ids as $id) {
            $values = explode(" ", $id);
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $final .= $value . ', ';
            }
            
        }
        
        echo rtrim($final, ', ') . '<br>';
        echo substr($final, 0, -2) . '<br>'; //other solution
    }
?>
```

Comment: are you sure that you copied all closing } ? this code should work only with an extra <BR/> in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use **trim()** function.

Well, if you have a string like this

> ```
>  $str="foo, bar, foobar,";
> ```

use this code to remove the Last comma

```
<?Php
$str="foo, bar, foobar,";
$string = trim($str, " ,");
echo $string;
```

output: foo, bar, foobar

Answer (score 0):

If your array looks like;

```
[0] => 1,
[1] => 2,
[2] => 3,
...
```

The following should suffice (not the most optimal solution);

```
$string = '';  // Create a variable to store our future string.
$iterator = 0; // We will need to keep track of the current array item we are on.

if ( is_array( $ids ) ) 
{
   $array_length = count( $ids ); // Store the value of the arrays length

   foreach ( $ids as $id ) // Loop through the array
   {
      $string .= $id; // Concat the current item with our string

      if ( $iterator >= $array_length ) // If our iterator variable is equal to or larger than the max value of our array then break the loop.
        break;

      $string .= ", "; // Append the comma after our current item.
      $iterator++; // Increment our iterator variable

   }
}

echo $string; // Outputs "1, 2, 3..."
```